# How to disable Amazon EC2 charging?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I currently try to implement amazon ec2 and I read that after one year they charge you. I used google app engine before(using java) and there is the feature that you can enable/disable charging. I just want to try the free ec2 instance, so here are my questions:

- Does Amazon EC2 AUTOMATICALLY charge you after one year?
- How to disable the automatically charging function?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is currently not possible to **disable charging**. You might need to **go over the free tier** (for example, if you set up a production environment, you might not want it to be killed automatically by Amazon). Google App engine is a bit different because it is free if you have zero HTTP requests, so it will just **stop serving your app**.

If you [delete your credit card](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=221554) on [your account](https://www.amazon.com/gp/css/account/cards/view.html), amazon will still charge it if there is an unpaid balance.

Amazon **will not remind you** that you will go over your free tier, so I recommend putting **a little reminder** in one year on your calendar not to forget to shut down your server.

Comment: is there probably a service that I can put a billing limit so that I do not get ruined...

Comment: there is not billing limit option.

Comment: No service exists to put a billing limit. You can configure an alert to let you know that your bill has gone over a certain price but there is no way for them to kill your instances automatically if your limit is reached.

Comment: @bwight: there actually might be a way to set up a Cloudwatch alarm that triggers an SNS message that will trigger a service to terminate all your EC2 instances when your charges hit $0.01 (I doubt one cent would ruin @maximus). You could even schedule termination for a specific date.

Comment: Yes probably could hack something out that shutsdown all of your servers when the billing trips the CloudWatch alarm. I don't know of anything that already exists, but I don't see any reason why it couldn't be built.

Comment: In 2017 they state the free tier includes free products that never expire. If I'm not mistaken that includes the EC2 Instances

Answer (score 34):

I ended up closing my account by visiting the [account page](https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home?#/account)

At the bottom of the page you will find "close account"

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It is really hard to find.

Comment: thank you so much. that was really hard to find and makes me want to avoid working with amazon.

Comment: but you can actually still continue to be billed if you have any recurring payment and EC2 is one?

Answer (score 8):

There is no way to control how much you will have to pay on AWS, that's why I wouldn't use it.

Amazon is really vague on the free tier (for instance it's not very clear whether the storage volume comes with the instance is counted against free EB2 storage quota). There are so many ways you can get a bill for using the free tier.

Yes you will be billed after 12 months, if you don't terminate all the instances and detach all storage volumes.

So many people have complained about Amazon's billing practice. Amazon has never changed. I guess this is the way Amazon decided to make $. Let you in for "free" but you will most likely accidentally spend some money. If you decide to use it, you won't know how much you will have to pay. If you have the capability to use colo/dedicated server, you might find out it's actually so much cheaper to go with a fixed monthly payment instead of billing based on usage.

Comment: the t1.micro instances (which are free in the free tier) don't have any storage other than EBS, so the point about it not being clear if it's counted is moot. Other than that, you're right, any responsible organisation should be doing the math to compare self-hosting, dedicated servers and cloud services. In our case, for example, we use a mix of dedicated servers for the base line systems and cloud servers for load spikes and temporary use.

Comment: Couldn't agree with you more. There are so many ways you can get a bill for using the free tier.

Answer (score 7):

With Amazon EC2, you are billed per hour of usage. If you are a new user, your account is credited with something like 8,760 free hours (24*365) which expire after 1 year. (I'm working from fuzzy memory here, so double-check the official terms instead of taking my word for it.)

After your free hours expire or are otherwise used up, Amazon EC2 will begin billing for normal hours (which can be as cheap as 2 cents per hour -- http://ec2instances.info). There is no such thing as a "free" EC2 instance.

So, to answer your questions:

> - Does Amazon EC2 AUTOMATICALLY charge you after one year?

Once your free hours are used up or expire, then you are automatically billed for normal hourly usage.

> - How to disable the automatically charging function?

You can't. All EC2 instances cost money. You are responsible for keeping an eye on your account and ensuring that you don't go over your free hours if you don't want to pay anything.

Comment: Currently at 750 hrs / month.  A 31 day month has 744 hrs.

Answer (score 3):

I was charged for a service that practically i never used.

a) Its true that Amazon never told you that the free tier is done.   However, Amazon is prompty to charges you.  Its my mistake but i admit that a little advice doesn't hurt, specially since practicaly everybody do that.

b) Even for a free tier, i wasn't impressed with the performance.  I am owned a shared-hosting that are more powerful.

c) As some comments said, you can't delete your credit card, neither you can cancels the service. Its really low.

d) Finally,as some comment said, i closed my account. As far i can remember, its not tied with your Amazon (not cloud) account.

The service its so convoluted and overly complex, its filled with paid-traps and i am not impressed at all.   Thanks Amazon but not thanks, i will stick with VPS/Dedicated.

Answer (score 0):

You get 1 year of free usage http://aws.amazon.com/free/ .

Try reading AWS Free Usage Tier: [http://www.amazon.com/Getting-Started-Guide-Usage-ebook/dp/B007Q4JESC/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1343213452&sr=8-1&keywords=aws+free+tier](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007Q4JESC) .